# dynamically created tabs and tab selection from code - VMWare Clarity Design

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have an  angular component to dynamically create form and grid for CRUD. The meta data comes from an API.

It also create Tabs dynamically depending on the metadata  and one Tab by default declaratively in template. dynamic tabs are done with *ngFor in template html and then the declaration for the default tab.

Now my task is to select the first tab in the series from component code. By default angular/clarity selects the tab which was declared in template.

I cant use *clrIfActive as I cant have lazy lading of form controls which are laid out in various tabs as i am binding various things (for eg, for the Select Control data comes from backend and options are created dynamically)..effectively I need all the controls accessible in the form on ngInit. So *clrIfActive directive is out.

Need a way to select the first tab(one of the dynamic ones) programatically.

I just cant seem to be able to do it.

I did a viewChild reference to 'clrTabs' and inspected it(ngAfterViewInit)..all my tabs are listed.however, cant seem to get at the REQUIRED tab thru tabLinkDirectives to activate it. tabLinkDirectives.first and last point to the tab that was declared in the template. However, _results show the array with dynamically created ones also.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but its kind of hard to understand what you have and what you are trying to accomplish. I created a starter stackblitz that creates tabs dynamically with `*ngFor` here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v1-0-so-53771507-dynamic-tabs-question Can you fork it and modify it so that I can better understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: hello @hippeelee..  i forked..https://clarity-v1-0-so-53771507-dynamic-tabs-question-re5nwg.stackblitz.io  Now what I want is to select Dashboard tab from code.

Comment: @hippeelee In the stackblitz you have given ..the tab selection seems to default to the first Tab. In my case(in my app not on stackblitz fork) , it seems to select the last tab which I declared in template .. I am using v0.13..stackblitz example on 1.0 ? In any case, how do I select a particular TAB (eg, cloud) from code ??

Comment: I added an answer with some sample apps for both v1.0.0 and v0.13.0. Can we discuss there?

Comment: @hippeelee..pardon my ignorance.. added and discuss where ?

Answer (score 2):

## Updated Answer:

In addition to the First answer below, try subscribing to the `@ViewChildren` changes and then running your tab selection method/logic after the tabs are added (or removed). Here is the subscription code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.tabLinks.changes.subscribe(tabChange => {
    this.activateFirstTab();
  });
}
```

And here is a stackblitz showing it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v013-so-53771507-dynamic-tabs-question-agqn8x

---

## Original Answer

You can gat a `QueryList` for all of the tab links like this

```
@ViewChildren(ClrTabLink) tabLinks: QueryList<ClrTabLink>;
```

Then, you can find any of the tabs in that list and `activate()` it like this:

```
  activateFirstTab() {
    this.tabLinks.first.activate();
  }
```

I used the same code from the stackblitzes above in both Clarity v0.13 and Clarity v1.0.0 and I always have the first tab selected after the app initializes. If your app is behaving differntly can you recreate that issue in a stackblitz?

Here is the [v0.13 stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v013-so-53771507-dynamic-tabs-question) and here is the [v1.0.0 stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v1-0-so-53771507-dynamic-tabs-question-4qj2fj)

Comment: @user2533922 this shows you how to get a list of `clrTabLinks` and then activate one of them with the click of a button. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for the help..however, I definitely seem to have a problem as i am getting only ONE TAB (the one declared in the template and NONE of the dynamically created ones)..and console.log shows clrTabLink instead of QueryList as in your case. May be some life cycle issue ?? However, all the TABS are in the UI as epxected...and the default selection goes to the tab which was declared in the template.. is ngAfterViewInit guranteed to be the last life cycle hook ? Anything you can think of /

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a life cycle issue from what you describe. If you can recreate the issue you describe in a stackblitz I’d be happy to look at it and see what’s going on.

Comment: @user2533922 If you get only one tab and ClrTabLink instead of QueryList, it means you're probably using `@ContentChild` instead of `@ContentChildren`.

Comment: @Eudes.. No Sir.. using only ViewChild

Comment: @hippeelee Here is the stackblitz to simulate close to my setup.. It looks pretty much like a timing issue...I have given a delay of 1 sec to fill the tab values.. and the result is pretty much same as mine.. the tab that was declared in the template gets activated by default.. however, in mycase i cant even do the switching thru button click.... In my case, I have a couple of async calls to backend get the meta data for the tabs,form controls etc.. Hope it gives you an idea of the situation and guide me... https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v013-so-53771507-dynamic-tabs-question-6vqjtk

Comment: @hippeelee Thank you for that..looks like it is just what the doctored ordered on stackblitz..will try out in my code....

Comment: Awesome, please let me know if it works and helps you by accepting my answer or updating me with whats not working.